# have a negation and an AND in an IF statemnt for conditional formatting in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to change the current cell if a different cell is not blank AND if it is four days later then the date in that cell.

Why doesn't this work and would would be a solution that does?

```
= IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(E12)), TODAY())) >  (E12 + 4)
```

I want it to check if the date cell is blank, if it is then I want the formula to cease, then if the condition has a value I want it see if todays date is greater then the other cells value plus 4. If it is, the conditional format will go into effect and turn the cell red. I'm basically trying to mimic and ELSEIF statement with an AND

Comment: This is more of what I'm trying, but also not working.

    = IF( NOT(ISBLANK(E12) ), TRUE, FALSE), IF(TODAY() >  (E12 + 4), TRUE, FALSE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, figured it out, if you're having the same issue here's a working solution.

```
= IF(IF(ISBLANK(E12), FALSE, TRUE), IF((TODAY() >  (E12 + 4)), TRUE, FALSE))
```